# PHP: Convertir array a texto plano

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

¿Hay alguna manera de convertir fácilmente un array escalar de PHP a texto plano para que pueda ser incluido en un `WHERE` de MySQL?

Es decir, convertir esto (el número de elementos puede ser variable, con un mínimo de 1):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '25' (length=2)
  1 => string '26' (length=2)
```

En una cadena de texto tal que así:

```
$ids = "(25, 26)";
```

De manera que a continuación se pueda pasar a un consulta SQL de esta manera:

```
...
WHERE
    id IN $ids
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro:

```
$ids = implode(', ', $array);

$query = "..... WHERE id IN (" . $ids . ")";
```

Y si los valores tuvieran que ser cadenas:

```
$ids = implode("', '", $array);

$query = "..... WHERE id IN ('" . $ids . "')";
```

Aunque en ese caso sería conveniente asegurarte de que ningún valor te fastidia la consulta (por ejemplo, porque contiene una comilla ').